# How to host Angular 8 application on IIS

Tags: angular, angular8

I am working on an angular 8 project(with seperate API project), I need to host it on my local IIS.

I followed [this](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis-60a0897742e7) link but getting below error.

I have created an application on `IIS` named as `AngularCrud` which is mapped to `dist` folder of my project, and used the command `ng build --base-href "/AngularCrud/" --prod` to build the application.

Added a `web.config` in `src` folder contains same code as given in link.

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
//also tried with below line
<action type="Rewrite" url="/AngularCrud/" />
```

**Note:** My `dist` folder contain `AngularCrud` subfolder which actually contains published code.

[image: ang]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search I found the solution.

No need for any `webconfig` here, just need to run `ng build --base-href "/AngularCrud/" --prod` and map the IIS application to the published code directory `dist/AngularCrud` worked for me.